# Find the number of lost items in each group (ORACLE SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Say I have the following table with these records

Table: COMPARE_INDIV

```
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| ID_GROUP | INDIV_ID_OLD | INDIV_ID_NEW |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
|        1 |          123 | 567          |
|        1 |          123 | null         |
|        1 |          123 | 123          |
|        2 |          891 | null         |
|        2 |          891 | 456          |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

I want to insert entries into a table called COUNTS that counts the number of lost INDIV_ID_OLD for each GROUP_ID in the COMPARE_INDIV table. A INDIV_ID_OLD is lost if the INDIV_ID_OLD does not exists in the INDIV_ID_NEW column for each GROUP_ID. In this case, the COUNTS table would look like this.

Table: COUNTS

```
+----------+------------+--+
| ID_GROUP | LOST_COUNT |  |
+----------+------------+--+
|        1 |          0 |  |
|        2 |          1 |  |
+----------+------------+--+
```

How would I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select id_group, sum(1 - present) as missing
from (select id_group, indiv_id_old,
             max(case when individ_id_new = indiv_id_old then 1 else 0 end) as present
      from COMPARE_INDIV ci
      group by id_group, indiv_id_old
     ) ci
group by id_group;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, but only one aggregation:

```
SQL> with compare_indiv (id_group, indiv_id_old, indiv_id_new) as
  2  -- sample data
  3    (select 1, 123, 567  from dual union all
  4     select 1, 123, null from dual union all
  5     select 1, 123, 123  from dual union all
  6     select 2, 891, null from dual union all
  7     select 2, 891, 456  from dual
  8    ),
  9  temp as
 10  -- SUM will be 0 if nothing matches
 11    (select id_group,
 12       sum(case when indiv_id_old = indiv_id_new then 1 else 0 end) sumon
 13     from compare_indiv
 14     group by id_group
 15    )
 16  -- final result
 17  select id_group,
 18    case when sumon = 0 then 1 else 0 end lost_count
 19  from temp
 20  /

  ID_GROUP LOST_COUNT
---------- ----------
         1          0
         2          1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe exists a better form, but this is one solution for you

```
INSERT INTO COUNTS
SELECT A.ID_GROUP , sum(A.is_lost) LOST_COUNT
FROM
(
    SELECT  A.ID_GROUP ,  A.INDIV_ID_OLD
            ,NVL((
                SELECT 0
                FROM COMPARE_INDIV B
                WHERE   A.ID_GROUP      = B.ID_GROUP
                AND     A.INDIV_ID_OLD  = B.INDIV_ID_NEW
                AND     ROWNUM          = 1
            ),1) is_lost
    FROM        COMPARE_INDIV A
    GROUP BY A.ID_GROUP , A.INDIV_ID_OLD
) A
GROUP BY A.ID_GROUP
```